# Using Eigen as matrix library in Omnetpp

Tags: c++, matrix, omnet++

I have used Eigen as a matrix library. How to assign the matrix variable to NULL. I tried `MatrixXd mat = NULL;` but there is an error:

> conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'Eigen::MatrixXd {aka Eigen::Matrix}' requested MatrixXd mat = NULL;

How to assign null values in the beginning to the matrix?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Matrix class has static methods like Zero(), which can be used to initialize all coefficients to zero. Try `MatrixXd mat = MatrixXd::Zero(row, col);`.

You can read about this here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a724349af3e253b69a54d503931b52ec3

Comment: double col; 
double row;
MatrixXd mat = MatrixXd::Zero(row, col);   I have tried as you suggested but I got random values instead of zero in the matrix. Is there any other way so that I can initialize the matrix to zero. I went through the site as well but could not get any hint. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only *pointers* can be `NULL`:

```
MatrixXd* mat = NULL;
```